# Azure Function For Monitoring Edge Module Health

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, health-monitoring, azure-functions-core-tools

I  want to create an azure function to monitor the health of my edge modules in the iothub. By Retrieving the twin Properties of the module i will be able to do it.
Infact i have a C# code which is giving the desired result. But I am very new to the concept of azure functions and i am stuck on how to work with them.
following is the code i am using to retrieve module twin properties:

```
public class TwinSample
{
    private ModuleClient _moduleClient;

    public TwinSample(ModuleClient moduleClient)
    {
        _moduleClient = moduleClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(moduleClient));
    }

    public async Task<string> RunSampleAsync()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Retrieving twin...");
        Twin twin = await _moduleClient.GetTwinAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        Console.WriteLine("\tInitial twin value received:");

        Console.WriteLine($"\t{twin.ToJson()}");
        return twin.ToJson();
    }


}

 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s_moduleConnectionString) && args.Length > 0)
        {
            s_moduleConnectionString = args[0];
        }

            ModuleClient moduleClient = ModuleClient.CreateFromConnectionString(s_moduleConnectionString, s_transportType);

            var sample = new TwinSample(moduleClient);
            Sample.RunSampleAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.ReadLine();


    }
```

Can any one explain me how to make the same functionality work in azure function?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which trigger you want to use (the condition to run your Function). Here is a sample for Timer based function:

```cs
public static class MyApp 
{
    [FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
    public static async Task Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer)
    {
        var moduleConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ModuleConnectionString", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
        var transportType = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TransportType", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

        ModuleClient moduleClient = ModuleClient.CreateFromConnectionString(moduleConnectionString, transportType);

        var sample = new TwinSample(moduleClient);
        await sample.RunSampleAsync();
    }
}
```

Definition of `TwinSample` can be reused from your original code.

You would need to set the values for `ModuleConnectionString` and `TransportType` in Application settings of Azure Functions (e.g. via the portal).

P.S. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a bit broad for the standards of this site, because it just asks "how do I do this" instead of giving the code/approach that you already tried. Next time, please go though Getting Started samples of Azure Functions and try to apply your code to them before asking a question.